# Find lower price among repeated ID

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have sheet 1 contain col An ID and col B is the price and col An is repeated ; how can I find the lowest price among colum B for the same ID

```
=MIN(IF(D1=Sheet2!$D$2:Sheet2!$D$562;Sheet2!$M$2:$M$562))
```

It always return `0`.

I am using Excel 2013

Comment: enter it as an ***array formula***

Comment: to enter as an array formula instead of just pressing enter when you are finished with the formula, press control+shift+enter